# Unwrapping error with optional in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make some connections with an API and I need to return an error message if the username is unknown. Though, while I try to print my variable in my post request, I see the message but if I print my variable after my request but in my function, I have an error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)`.

Here is a sample of my code. I use SwiftHTTP for my requests:

```
var errSign: String?
func signUp(email:String, pwd:String) {
    let params: Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = ["password": pwd, "email": email]

    task.POST(signUpUrl, parameters: params, completionHandler: {(response: HTTPResponse) -> Void in
        if let err = response.error {
            println("error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }
        if let json = response.responseObject as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            var data = JSON(json)
            if data["error"] != false {
                self.errSign = String(stringInterpolationSegment: data["error"])
                println(self.errSign!)
            }
        }
    })
    // ERROR println(self.errSign!)
}
```

Comment: I think 'var data = JSON(json!)' because json is optional in your cast.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `errSign` as optional, so you should probably check to see that there's something in there before attempting to print anything out:

```
self.errSign = String(stringInterpolationSegment: data["error"])
if let actualErrSign = self.errSign
{
    println(\(actualErrSign))
} else {
    println("no (obvious) error was returned")
}
```

Comment: I haven't fully understood your code. Your code works but how can I return my error message ? Because in this case, actualErrSign is equal to my expected error message of my api but i'm again in my request and I want return the value after the post function, in my signUp function

Comment: If I understand what you're now asking (which is a separate & new question), it sounds like you want to *return* any possible error as a return value from your `signUp` function?

Answer (score 0):

the ! keyword is to unwrap an optional variable to access to its value. This is only possible when your optional variable contains a value. In case you try to unwrap an optional variable that does not hold actually a value, your application will crash and it receive that fatal error.

The solution is in the answer of @Michael Dautermann

Comment: Yes but in this case, actualErrSign is equal to my expected error message of my api but i'm again in my request and I want return the value after the post function, in my signUp function

Comment: in my opinion, you self.errSign does not contain any value. Can you show the value of data["error"] ? Add a breakpoint to println(self.errSign!), you will see that self.errSign is nil.